# (Python/ Regular Expression) How to select text between two given words?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Langaue(Python3.X, Re library)**

I have a string as follows

```
import re
query_string = r'SELECT "a"."name", "a"."create_date", "a"."state", SUM("b"."cost") AS "amount", SUM("b"."cost") FILTER (WHERE "a"."state" = 'UNPAID') AS "paid", SUM("b"."cost") FILTER (WHERE "a"."state" = 'PAID') AS "unpaid" FROM "maintenance"'
```

I want to select "column names" i.e. `"a"."name", "a"."create_date", "a"."state"`. from above string.

Which comes between `"SELECT" and "SUM(.*)"`
Any help appreciated.

I have tried below Regular Expression pattern

1. `r'SELECT (.* ), [^(SUM(.* )]'`
2. `r'SELECT (.* ), SUM(.* )'`

but both are not giving accurate result

**Expected result:**

```
 "a"."name", "a"."create_date", "a"."state"(No comma at the endth)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:SELECT\s*)(.*?)(?:,\s*SUM.*)
```

to create a single capturing group.

The two `(?:...)` make non-capturing groups.
The `(.*?)` is a non-greedy group, which will stop before the FIRST "SUM" instead of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(SELECT\s*)([^()]+)(,\s*SUM.*)
```

and use the second group with `\2`. Or replace groups `\1` and `\3` with nothing.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/iBc0X2/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sql = '''SELECT "a"."name", "a"."create_date", "a"."state", SUM("b"."cost") AS "amount", SUM("b"."cost") FILTER (WHERE "a"."state" = 'UNPAID') AS "paid", SUM("b"."cost") FILTER (WHERE "a"."state" = 'PAID') AS "unpaid" FROM "maintenance"'''

res = re.search(r'SELECT (.+?), SUM', sql)
print(res.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
"a"."name", "a"."create_date", "a"."state"
```

Comment: You can find the explanation of `(.+?)` under my answer. It is the "at least one" version of the `(.*?)` "zero or more" I used. This is why code-only answers are considered less helpful than answers with some explanation.

Comment: @AjayPhape: `.+?` means 1 or more any character, not greedy (I.e. it matches the less characters it can). See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html